# how can i calculate two values continuously

Tags: php

i have set `$s=(2+$len)`. so when i click continue the value of start will be 4 and i would like it to become 6 / 8 automatically as i click continue again.

```
$number=array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'g',    'j');
$start=2;
$len=2;
$s=(2+$len);
foreach ($number as $value) {     
    print_r($value) ; 
}
echo '<br>'.'<br>';
if (isset($_GET['start']))
    $start= $_GET['start'];
foreach (array_slice($number,$start,$len) as $k){
    print_r($k);
}
echo '<br>'.'<br>';
echo '<a href="http://192.168.1.6/alpha.php?start='.$s.'&len=2">
continue</a>';
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Write a function.

Comment: use session for increment

Comment: create $s as a session variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a session (then you cannot "skip" anything by changing the URL), but it seems like you've already started to use `$_GET` for this (seeing as your target URL is `alpha.php?start=' . $s . '&len=2`). Seems as though both `$len` and `$s` should be set from `$_GET`, if a parameter in the URL is set.

The two variables should be altered to the following

```
$len = isset($_GET['len']) ? (int)$_GET['len'] : 2; // This means that you 'can' drop &len=2 from the link
$s = isset($_GET['start']) ? (int)$_GET['start']+2 : 2; // This ensures that you always increment it by 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `$start = 2;` using the `$_GET` you already have...

```
$number=array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'g',    'j');
//Start is now what is in $_GET if it is set or 2
$start = isset($_GET['start'])) ? $_GET['start'] : 2;
$len = 2;
$s = (2 + $len);

foreach($number as $value) {
    print_r($value);
}

echo '<br />' . '<br />';

if (isset($_GET['start'])) $start = $_GET['start'];

foreach(array_slice($number, $start, $len) as $k) {
    print_r($k);
}

echo '<br />' . '<br />';
echo '<a href="http://192.168.1.6/alpha.php?start=' . $s . '&len=2">continue</a>';
?>
```